# Controller Method not found -AmbiguousActionException

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to call the httpget method of a controller.But its always 404.I have added all required directives.When i call the class name directly i get this exception

```
AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:
```

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

// For more information on enabling Web API for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ScannerController : Controller
    {

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> dostuff(string file_id)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

***Startup.cs***

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using WebApplication2.Models;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {

            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });

            // requires using Microsoft.Extensions.Options
            services.Configure<DatabaseSettings>(
                Configuration.GetSection(nameof(DatabaseSettings)));

            services.AddSingleton<IDatabaseSettings>(sp =>
                sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<DatabaseSettings>>().Value);


        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            //app.UseSpaStaticFiles();


            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are calling GET api/scanner/dostuff?

Comment: this look strange [Route("api/[controller]")]

Comment: @RicardoPeres yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the route on the `dostuff` method to:

```
[HttpGet("dostuff")]
```